# Это проблема с файловой системой?

Tags: linux

Файловая система BTRFS.

Погас свет, теперь с временными файлами Postgresql наблюдаю такую картину. Удалить нельзя. Это проблема с файловой системой?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Попробуйте btrfs check --repair

Comment: ОК. Секунду. Самое время делать Backup))

Comment: Сделал btrfs check --repair Не помогло.